# Creating a macro with a modified (uppercase) name

Tags: macros, expl3

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do, whose intent should be obvious (see the comments).

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \sayhello { } {
    Hello
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \foo { m } {
    \use:c {
        \MakeUppercase{\cs_to_str:N #1}
    }
    again
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\foo{\sayhello} % Should construct \SAYHELLO macro.

\begin{document}

    \sayhello % Should output "Hello".

    \SAYHELLO % Should output "Hello again".

\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.18 \foo{\sayhello}
```

I suppose I'm missing some appropriate expansion in the above code, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: This has garnered a vote to close and I'm at a loss to understand why. Yes, it seems a strange thing to do but I can well imagine that the real use-case is sufficiently intricate that if the OP had posted that then there'd be comments asking them to trim it down! I frequently find it useful to test my understanding of things by considering edge cases that I'd never use in a real document (not that I'm saying I'd never use this - I actually have used something quite similar)

Comment: @AndrewStacey "whose intent should be obvious"  = no willingness to precisely describe the problem -> need for clarification -> reason for closing

Comment: @UlrichDiez My reading would have been "whose intent should be obvious" = thought they had precisely described the problem, so if I need clarification -> reason for *commenting*. To vote to close *without a comment* feels a bit harsh to me.

Comment: @AndrewStacey You are quite right. I'm not actually trying to create an uppercase version of a macro, but I've tried to make my example "minimal", since my real use case involves `\MakeUppercase` in a more intricate way.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I presume you read the (short) code, however? I'm pretty confident that everything that is not self-explanatory (which `\sayhello` surely is) is appropriately commented. You're welcome to ask for clarification if not. Anyway, I appreciate that you've given an answer!

Comment: For the record: I have retracted my vote to close. I think my objectivity was clouded by physical pain. In the immediate foreseeable future, I will refrain from making any judgments that do not concern myself.

Comment: @UlrichDiez No worries. Sorry to hear you’re suffering from physical pain.

Comment: @Noldorin Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to actually define the upper case variant. The way your current code works would just directly try to call the upper case named variant whenever you use `\foo` while it's not yet defined.

Also, you can't use `\MakeUppercase` inside of `\use:c` (or `\csname ...\endcsname`) because it isn't expandable. Instead you could use `\str_uppercase:n` provided by `expl3`. The following uses the `f`-variant of that to first expand `\cs_to_str:N` before upper casing happens.

Note that this `\foo` does only work for parameterless macros.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \foo { m }
  {
    \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { \str_uppercase:f { \cs_to_str:N #1 } } {}
      { #1~ again }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand \sayhello {} {Hello}
\foo\sayhello

\begin{document}
\sayhello

\SAYHELLO
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does the job nicely.

Comment: Accepting this, since it provides a succinct solution, though I certainly appreciate @UlrichDiez's explanation concerning `\MakeUppercase` too!

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with `\MakeUppercase` is that

- a processing-cascade is triggered which also yields non-expandable tokens that are not suitable as components of names of control sequence tokens.
- the result is delivered nested in a curly-brace-group.

`\MakeUppercase` is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\MakeUppercase[1]{%
  {% -- opening brace of brace-group
    \def\i{I}%
    \def\j{J}%
    \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##1##2\reserved@a}%
    \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
    \let\UTF@two@octets@noexpand\@empty
    \let\UTF@three@octets@noexpand\@empty
    \let\UTF@four@octets@noexpand\@empty
    \protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{#1}}%
    \reserved@a % -- this holds the text wrapped in \uppercase, some symbol-delivering control-sequences replaced by control-sequences that yield the uppercase variant
  }% -- closing brace of brace-group
}%
```

`\MakeUppercase` is intended for typesetting-purposes, not for the purpose of providing/modifying names of control-sequence-tokens.

For programming-purposes/for the purpose of providing/modifying names of control-sequence-tokens expl3 brings along `\str_uppercase:n`/`\str_uppercase:f`.

**Not for daily usage, just for exhibiting the problem** the code below provides a variant of `\MakeUppercase` where things are not placed into a curly-brace-group.

In any case `\str_uppercase:n`/`\str_uppercase:f` is to be preferred in the context of names of control-sequences:
`\MakeUppercase`'s uppercasing routine depends on the font-encoding and might deliver tokens which, when typeset, yield the uppercase-variant of the symbol in question, but cannot be used as components of macro-names.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\MyMakeUppercase[1]{%
  {%
    \def\i{I}%
    \def\j{J}%
    \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##1##2\reserved@a}%
    \expandafter\reserved@a \@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
    \let\UTF@two@octets@noexpand\@empty
    \let\UTF@three@octets@noexpand\@empty
    \let\UTF@four@octets@noexpand\@empty
    \protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{#1}}%
    % \show\reserved@a
  \expandafter}\reserved@a
}%
\makeatother


\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\sayhello{}{Hello}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \foo { m } {
    \MyMakeUppercase{\exp_not:n{\exp_args:Nc\NewDocumentCommand}{\cs_to_str:N #1}}{}
    {#1~again}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\foo{\sayhello} % Should construct \SAYHELLO macro.

\begin{document}

    \sayhello % Should output "Hello".

    \SAYHELLO % Should output "Hello again".

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.